# Why does malloc() return a pointer and it doesnt return directly an address?

Tags: c, memory, malloc

I recently started programming in C and i was wondering why malloc() returns a pointer instead of an address. Wouldn't be easier to return an address directly ?

I was thinking about it and I couldn't understand the reasoning behind it.

Comment: A pointer is variable that holds an address.  It is an address.

Comment: A pointer is a location into memory. Where that memory is doesn't matter.
There are systems that have Near and Far addresses. A pointer lets you abstract this away

Comment: What would you do with this "address"? You need to dereference a pointer to access the object allocated by `malloc()`.

Answer (score -1):

In C, a pointer is a variable that holds the memory address of another variable. Therefore, returning a pointer provides a convenient and standardized way to represent the address of the allocated memory.

In layman's terms, you are returning the address.

Comment: Not all variables have an address. Not all pointers reference a variable.

Answer (score -1):

For beginners, always think: pointers == addresses. This holds true in most scenarios.

(Beginners can stop reading here.)

---

Advanced topic:

There are some cases where pointers have a couple of limitations that addresses don't, such as when performing pointer arithmetic - we can only do so on a pointer pointing at an array. Whereas in case of addresses we can obviously access any address directly if the hardware/system allows it. So for example if you say there's a variable of a certain type at address 0x1234, then use a pointer to such a variable to access the following addresses, that's in theory undefined behavior (which is inconvenient when doing hardware-related programming).

The rationale for this is supposedly because pointers aren't necessarily pointing at contiguous memory addresses and that in theory they could have different representations depending on the pointed-at type. Systems with fragmented memory maps and extended addresses is a thing.

However, all such systems tend to not hide when it is using such a specialized pointers internally, but rather force the programmer to explicitly demand one, by means of the common (but non-standard) keywords `near` and `far`, where a `near`-qualified pointer points within the standard address range, and a `far` one at the extended range. These keywords are often used both for object pointers and function pointers.

So overall, the flexibility of implementation that C allows for when making pointers some abstract, magical entities rather than just addresses, is rarely ever used in practice. And because of this, plain programs on mainstream systems suffer all manner of undefined behavior when doing things like pointer arithmetic outside declared arrays. Not ideal for hardware-related programming. As a work-around, arithmetic on a `uintptr_t` may be more well-defined than using a pointer type directly.